# 500 Internal Server Error on Django App Deployment on Render.com

Tags: python, django, postgresql, deployment, render.com

I am encountering a persistent `500 Internal Server Error` when trying to deploy my Django project on Render.com. The error message is not providing detailed information, and I am struggling to diagnose the issue.

Here's the error log from Render:

127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2024:18:01:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-"

The project runs fine locally, but the problem occurs when I deploy it to Render. I have configured my `settings.py` for production as follows (relevant parts shown):

```py
# settings.py

import os
from pathlib import Path
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.com', 'renderproject.onrender.com']

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
}

# Static files settings
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# ...other settings...
```

My requirements.txt includes all the necessary packages like Django, gunicorn, psycopg2-binary, whitenoise, etc.

I am looking for suggestions on what could be causing this error and how to resolve it. Any insights or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated!

---

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BAjv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3M2C.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwOKC.png)python, django, deployment, render, http-status-code-500

I have tried deploying my Django application on Render.com, expecting it to run as smoothly as it does on my local development environment. The application functions correctly locally, with all views rendering as expected and no errors in the console or logs.

Upon deployment to Render, however, I encounter a persistent 500 Internal Server Error. This error occurs when trying to access the homepage or any other route in the application. I expected the deployed application to be accessible and functional, similar to its local counterpart, but instead, I am faced with this server error.

I've ensured that all necessary environment variables, including SECRET_KEY and DATABASE_URL, are properly set in the Render environment. My settings.py file has been configured for production, with DEBUG set to False and ALLOWED_HOSTS updated accordingly.

The error log from Render is not very descriptive, only showing the 500 error with a basic GET request log. This has made it difficult to diagnose the exact cause of the issue.

I am seeking assistance in understanding why this error is occurring and how to resolve it to get my Django application running smoothly on Render.com.

Comment: Few points: 1. is this correct for ALLOWED_HOSTS? 'mydomain.com', 'renderproject.onrender.com', make sure to get this right. 2. You should be able to read nginx error logs which will give you a better idea of where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing Server error issues on render, you will need to set `PORT = 80` in the environment variables, also make sure that your app is set to listen on 0.0.0.0 and not localhost or 127.0.0.1

According to render, it’s possible to disable the automatic detection by setting your own PORT environment variable. This is also helpful if you run multiple HTTP processes on a Web Service, setting your own PORT will specify which process is accessible from the public internet.

read more : https://docs.render.com/web-services#host-and-port-configuration